# What is the difference between SoC FPGA and 'regular' FPGA?

Tags: fpga, soc

I've recently developed an interest in implementing projects on top of an FPGA dev board, and wish to purchase one such as the Altera [DE1](http://www.terasic.com.tw/cgi-bin/page/archive.pl?Language=English&CategoryNo=53&No=83&PartNo=2).

Looking in the company's site, I noticed there is another class of FPGAs called "SoC FPGAs" (such as [DE1-SoC](http://www.terasic.com.tw/cgi-bin/page/archive.pl?Language=English&CategoryNo=167&No=836&PartNo=2)) which incorporates an ARM core.

How does it differ from a 'regular' FPGA?
Is it less flexible in terms of design?

Comment: It incorporates an ARM core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said it has an arm core, they also tend to have a smaller amount of fpga resources compared to a similar price fpga only part.

It's neat that it allows the a direct access to the fpga fabric and if remember right it can also share a DDR interface between arm and fpga section.

It's nice if you need to run part of your application in software like maybe a high level portion of a network processing stack or the control plane for data processing while doing complementary things in hardware.

If you don't need it though you're better off with a dedicated fpga.